# Prove that: $\sum _{c=1}^n \sum _{b=1}^n \sum _{a=1}^n \left(\left([b|c][b|a]\frac{\mu(b)b}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{a b\sqrt{c}}\right)<H_n+n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-inversion

In the OEIS there is the quote from Lowell Schoenfeld that the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to:

$$|\psi(n) - n| < \sqrt{n} \log^2(n)$$

From the Euler Maclaurin formula one gets:

$$\sum _{c=1}^n \sum _{b=1}^n \sum _{a=1}^n \frac{1}{a b\sqrt{c}} \approx \left(2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) (\log (n)+\gamma )^2$$

Mathematica knows that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{\left(2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) (\log (n)+\gamma )^2}{2 \sqrt{n} \log ^2(n)}=1$$

I believe the second Chebyshev function is approximately:
$$\psi(n) \approx -H_n+\sum _{c=1}^n \sum _{b=1}^n \sum _{a=1}^n \left([b|c][b|a]\frac{\mu(b)b}{a}\right) \tag{*}$$

which is essentially a Dirichlet convolution of two divisor matrices.

> *Question:* It then becomes natural to ask whether the following is true:
>
> $$-H_n -n +\sum _{c=1}^n \sum _{b=1}^n \sum _{a=1}^n\left(\left([b|c][b|a]\frac{\mu(b)b}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{ab\sqrt{c}}\right) <0 \tag{**}$$
>
> for $n=1,2,3,4,5,...$

I notice that: $$n=\sum _{c=1}^n \left(\sum _{b=1}^n \left(\sum _{a=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$ and: $$H_n=\sum _{c=1}^n \left(\sum _{b=1}^n \left(\sum _{a=1}^n \frac{1}{an^2}\right)\right)$$ which means we can rewrite $(**)$ as:

$$\sum _{c=1}^n \sum _{b=1}^n \sum _{a=1}^n\left(\left([b|c][b|a]\frac{\mu(b)b}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{ab\sqrt{c}} -\frac{1}{n^2} -\frac{1}{an^2} \right) <0 \tag{***}$$

Mathematica program to show the agreement in $(*)$:

```
nn = 20;
"This:"
Monitor[Table[
  Sum[Sum[Sum[
      If[Mod[c, b] == 0, 1, 0]*
        If[Mod[a, b] == 0, MoebiusMu[b]*b/a, 0] - 0/a/b/c^(1/2), {a, 
       1, n}], {b, 1, n}], {c, 1, n}] - HarmonicNumber[n], {n, 1, 
   nn}], n]
A = Table[Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
B = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[k, n] == 0, MoebiusMu[n]*n/k, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, 
    nn}];
TableForm[T = A.B];
"equals this:"
a1 = Table[
  Total[Total[T[[1 ;; m, 1 ;; m]]]] - HarmonicNumber[m], {m, 1, nn}]
Show[ListLinePlot[a1, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListLinePlot[Table[Total[MangoldtLambda[Range[n]]], {n, 1, nn}]]]
```

[image: Comparisons between approximate and precise actual Chebyshev functions]

The red curve is the Right Hand Side of $(*)$ and the blue curve is the actual second Chebyshev psi function  which is the Left Hand Side of $(*)$.

Mathematica program to explore the signs of the terms within the triple sum in $(***)$:

```
nn = 5;
Monitor[aaa = 
   Table[Sign[(Table[
       Table[Table[
         If[Mod[c, b] == 0, 1, 0]*
           If[Mod[a, b] == 0, MoebiusMu[b]*b/a, 0] - 1/a/b/c^(1/2) - 
          1/n^2 - 1/a/n^2, {a, 1, n}], {b, 1, n}], {c, 1, n}])], {n, 
     1, nn}];, n]
TableForm[aaa]
```

[image: sign patterns]

Comment: Come on, you don't need Mathematica for the third display. You look at it and see it (first semester calculus).